# Proof that whether a regular language is finite is decidable

Tags: computability, finite-automata, pumping-lemma, decision-problem

I have this question for a homework. The question stems from the fact that you can determine whether a regular language is empty by using a Turing machine to count the states *n* in the given FSM. When you generate all strings from length *0* to *n*, if the machine accepts any of them then the language is non-empty. We don't have to check words with length > *n* because of the pumping lemma.
The question claims that you can solve the decision problem for finiteness in a similar way.

I know intuitively that a regular language is finite if its finite, well-formed regular expression does not contain a Kleene star, but I don't know how to convert this notion around. My thought is that we have to know if there are any words in the language whose length is greather than *n*, but that requires checking all words.

Then I thought:
Have the machine count the number of states n in the FSM. Generate all of the strings of length *0* to *n*. Then, check every word to see if the only possible way to pump this word xyz is to make *y≡λ*. If every word pumps only according to this condition, then the language is finite. However, this feels somehow incomplete.

Could someone give me a hint or push me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: If you have a decider on regular expressions, what's the big deal? Convert the automaton to regular expressions (that's certainly computable) -- reduction obtained.

Comment: Alternatively, look at the *proof* of the Pumping lemma and see where the pumping comes from. That gives you one direction of the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that an NFA accepts an infinite language if and only if there is a (directed) path from the initial to an accepting state which contains at least one state more than once.

Comment: That's exactly it! I feel silly because we have discussed something similar, but he didn't directly link the ideas.

Answer (score 2):

If $L$ is infinite, it contains strings of unbounded length.  Think about the sequence of states visited by the automaton when these strings are accepted. This will give you a condition of the form "$M$ accepts an infinite language implies $X$".  Now check that it's actually "if and only if $X$."

Comment: I believe what you're hinting at is that a FSM that accepts an infinite language will have to visit at least one state at least twice. Clearly, a language is finite if none of the words cause the FSM to visit any state more than once. But I'm still stuck; we can't endlessly generate strings waiting waiting for one that visits a state twice.

Comment: @user327716 Look at the automaton, not the strings.

Answer (score 1):

How about checking all the strings of length $n$ to **2**$n$?
Would that be helpful to derive the required conclusion?

(In a sense, this is rephrasing your solution, right?)